# How do I insert a space after and before a dash that is not already surrounded by spaces?

Tags: python, regex, string

Let's say I have these strings:

```
string1= "Queen -Bohemian Rhapsody"

string2= "Queen-Bohemian Rhapsody"

string3= "Queen- Bohemian Rhapsody"
```

I want all of them to become to be like this:

```
   string1= "Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody"
   string2= "Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody"
   string3= "Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody"
```

How can I do this in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Match optional spaces before and after using the optional match qualifier '`?`' and replace with the normalized '` - `'.   See also https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Do you mean whitespace as in anything in the set `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` or a literal space character? For example, for `"Queen\t-\tBohemian Rhapsody"` as input, are you expecting tabs to be preserved as-is since there is already whitespace present, or replaced with spaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can regexp:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r"\s?-\s?") # \s? matches 0 or 1 occurenece of white space

# re.sub replaces the pattern in string
string1 = re.sub(pat, " - ", string1)
string2 = re.sub(pat, " - ", string2)
string3 = re.sub(pat, " - ", string3)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this overwrites whitespace characters that were present in the original string `"Queen\t-\tBohemian Rhapsody"` -> `"Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody"` If this is acceptable then this is almost certainly the best solution. If the requirement is to only insert whitespace if it didn't exist before (and otherwise don't touch it), another approach would be required.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't had that in mind. well if replacing is not allowed, then i guess this solution is not perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the help!